# how to find identical string in various columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to find the identical strings across as many columns and combinations as possible. for instance, I have a data like this

```
df<-structure(list(first = c("SNTM1", "STTTT2", "STOLA", "STOMQ", 
"STR2", "SUPTY1", "TBNHSG", "TEYAH", "TMEIL1", "TMEIL2", "TMEIL3", 
"TNIL", "TREUK", "TTRK", "TRRFK", "UBA52", "YIPF1", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), second = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SNTLK", "STTTFSG", "STOIU", "STOMQ", "STR25", 
"SUPYHGS", "TBHYDG", "TEHDYG", "TMEIL1", "YIPF1", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), second2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SNTLKM", "STTTFSGTT", "GFD", "STOMQ", 
"TRS", "BRsts", "TMHS", "RSEST", "TRSF", "YIPF1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-37L))
```

it has 3 columns, I want to find what is similar between column 1 and column 2 .
then 2 and 3 and then 1,2,3 together . SO the answer is like this

```
C1-C2   C2-C3 C1-C3   C1-C2-C3
STOMQ   STOMQ   STOMQ STOMQ
TMEIL1  YIPF1   YIPF1 YIPF1
YIPF1
```

which means C1(column1)-C2(column 2) share the only following identical strings

```
 STOMQ
TMEIL1
YIPF1
```

the same for other columns

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand `for` loops?

Comment: What about c1 and c3?

Comment: @onyambu
yes C1 and C3 ALSO, I add that too

Comment: Your question is incoherent. What do you mean by "the same for other columns"?? Are you finding intersect of all the columns or just intersect of 1,2,3,? Do you need intersect of 1,2? 1,3? 2,3 ? Or those are jist intermediate results?

Comment: @onyambu
 if you see the input and output, you can see that all combinations. if it was only two columns, I could simply do `match`

Comment: So you need 1,2| 1,3| 2,3 |1,2,3|. Note that they are of different lengths hence will be in a list instead of a dataframe

Comment: @onyambu
Yes Sir, that is super challenging for me, for binary , match works like a charm but when it comes to find identical in 3 columns, it is a pain, the same for higher number

Comment: If you want for 3 or more just use `Reduce(intersect, unname(df))`

Answer (score 5):

```
a <- combn(unname(df),2, do.call, what=intersect, simplify=FALSE)
```

`a` above contains the intersections of 1,2 and 1,3 and 2,3. Now to add the intersection of 1,2,3 to the list we do the below command: this add the intersection of 1,2,3 to the list a

```
c(a, list(intersect(a[[1]],a[[2]])))


[[1]]
[1] "STOMQ"  "TMEIL1" "YIPF1"  NA      

[[2]]
[1] "STOMQ" "YIPF1" NA     

[[3]]
[1] NA      "STOMQ" "YIPF1"

[[4]]
[1] "STOMQ" "YIPF1" NA
```

Comment: if you can somehow convert the answer to data frame without NA, I believe your answer is giving the trick

Comment: Nice answer. Don't know if it's simpler or more complex, but `combn(df, 2, FUN=\(x) intersect(x[[1]],x[[2]]), simplify=FALSE)` is also a possibility.

Comment: Instead of parking to `a`, pipe into `|> {\(.) c(.,  list(Reduce(intersect, .)))}()`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `accumulate()` from the purrr package as well as `intersect()` from base R to accomplish this. Something like:

```
library(purrr)

df <- map(df, ~ discard(.x, is.na)) 
# first remove NA values so they don't show up in intersect results

accumulate(df, ~ base::intersect(.x, .y))

# output

List of 3
 
  $first
    "SNTM1"  "STTTT2" "STOLA"  "STOMQ"  "STR2"   "SUPTY1" 
    "TBNHSG" "TEYAH"  "TMEIL1" "TMEIL2"
    "TMEIL3" "TNIL"   "TREUK"  "TTRK"   "TRRFK"  "UBA52"  "YIPF1" 

  $second
    "STOMQ"  "TMEIL1" "YIPF1" 

  $second2
    "STOMQ" "YIPF1"
```

$second is the result of taking the intersection of the first and second columns and corresponds to column C1-C2 in your example above. $second2 is the result of taking the intersection of this result and second2, which corresponds to C1-C2-C3 above.

Comment: it is not the answer amigo ! it is just removing the NA and set the data frame on fire to a list

Comment: Using a list avoids the problem of combining vectors of variable lengths into a dataframe (all columns must be of the same length). The result returned is a list of length 3, which contains the result of successively applying the intersect operation to each vector in df. 

Why does this not solve your problem?

Comment: look at the output that I am looking for, it is not even close , please look in my question

Comment: There is certainly a way to achieve this with `purrr` but as Nik already noted this does not answer the question unfortunately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).